# If Boolean variable true, increment i

Tags: javascript, p5.js, ml5.js

I have two Boolean variables `var lookingLeft = false`, `var lookingRight = false` and an ellipse `ellipse(40, 40, i, i)`.

```
var lookingLeft = false;
var lookingRight = false;

function draw() {

    let i = 30;
    ellipse(40, 40, i, i);
    
    if (nose.x > leftEye.x) {
      lookingLeft = true;
    }
    
    if (nose.x > rightEye.x) {
      lookingRight = true;
    }
    
    if (lookingLeft === true) {
      i = i + 10 //this is not working
      rect(10, 10, 50, 50); //but this is
    }
    
    if (lookingRight === true) {
      i = i - 10 //again, this is not working
      rect(300, 300, 50, 50); //but this is
    }
  }
```

I want `i` to increment by 10 when `lookingLeft = true` decrease by 10 when `lookingRight = true`.

Here's my p5 web editor sketch: https://editor.p5js.org/saskiasmith/sketches/7WMDPGPbrc

Many thanks!

Comment: `i = i + 10` or `i = i - 10`?

Comment: do you have other directiosn than left and right?

Comment: Thanks for your response @VLAZ but I already tried this but doesn't work in the sketch for some reason... not quite sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Then we need an [mcve] posted here in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is intentional or not, but you're re-assigning 'i' every time draw fires, so the max you can get is 40 and the min is 20. You could do something like this:

```
if(lookingLeft){ // if it's true it runs, you don't really need "===" with bools in if()
i += 10  //i = i + 10
} else if (lookingRight){
i -= 10
} else{  // OR else if(!lookingLeft && !lookingRight) {}"!" just means NOT so "if not looking left..."
i = 30
}

// and also there are more prettier ways to do this:  *I "explain" in the lower text*

i += (lookingRight) ? -10 : 10
if(!lookingRight && !lookingLeft){i = 30}
```

if you don't get it, i wouldn't advise using it in your code right now. But i might aswell try to explain it:
'(lookingRight)' is just if statement's thingy, '?' is the same as 'if', '-10' if true, '10' if not true, **but yet again this doesn't matter, I will not advise on using this...**

I also have no idea if that's what you meant and if this helps, so hope it does.

Answer (score 1):

You could add with the check.

```
i += lookingLeft && -10 || lookingRight && 10;
```

Or take the delta of the looking flags.

```
i += 10 * (lookingRight - lookingLeft);
```

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz, already tried this in the sketch but the size of the ellipse is not changing...

Answer (score 1):

You are firing the ellipse function before `i` is calcuted.
Once `ellipse` is fired, it doesn't matter what you do to `i`, the function ran.
Move the call to the back of `draw` and it should work.

```
var lookingLeft = false;
var lookingRight = false;

function draw() {
  let i = 30;
  
  if (nose.x > leftEye.x) {
    lookingLeft = true;
  }
  
  if (nose.x > rightEye.x) {
    lookingRight = true;
  }
  
  if (lookingLeft === true) {
    i = i + 10 //this is not working
  }
  
  if (lookingRight === true) {
    i = i - 10 //again, this is not working
  }

  ellipse(40, 40, i, i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, makes a lot of sense! Why does it only increment once though?

Comment: How do you mean?  your function starts with ```let i = 30```. then based on left or right you add/substract 10. so ```i``` can either be 20, 30 or 40, nothing else.